# Powershell: Reference a property that contains a space

Tags: powershell, csv

I am importing a CSV file using powershell.

The problem is, the title of one of the columns is "Remaining Time - Hours".
So I'm getting a sequence of objects, and it's actually assigned the property "Remaining Time - Hours".

What is the syntax to refer to this property?

eg

```
Import-Csv AllOpenCases.csv | % {$case = $_ }
$case | get-member
```

returns

```
Category               : Inquiry
Starred                : No
Remaining Time - Hours : 22.5
```

but if I type

```
$case.Remaining Time - Hours
```

I get "Unexpected token 'Time' in expression or statement"

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Properties with embedded spaces have to be quoted when they're referenced:

```
 $case."Remaining Time - Hours"
```

Comment: You've been a great help the last few weeks - thanks. Good that a question finally gives you high rep - funny that it's the simplest question. :-)

Comment: Thanks.  No offense intended to the site, but I count comments like that as better than the points and badges.

Comment: Really Good one! @mjolinor

Comment: This can also be found with the CSV object. `$csv = Import-Csv filename.csv` then type the name of the object with a dot `$csv.` and hit `TAB` several times to see the fields. `$csv | ft -a` can be used to check that the CSV file loaded correctly.

Comment: @Underverse thanks for mentioning that. In my case the property had a hiding space at the end and your comment helped me find that.

Answer (score 35):

Just to add, the property name can itself be a variable e.g.:

```
PS> $o = new-object psobject -prop @{'first name' = 'John'; 'last name' = 'Doe'}
PS> $o

last name                                         first name
---------                                         ----------
Doe                                               John


PS> $prop = 'first name'
PS> $o.$prop
John
```

Answer (score 29):

Or you can also wrap that property in { }. Like this:

```
 $case.{Remaining Time - Hours}
```

Answer (score 15):

FWIW, if it gets to be pain to code with, you can add an alias property:

```
 $caseprops = @"
 Category = Inquiry
 Starred = No
 Remaining Time - Hours = 22.5
 "@
 $case = new-object psobject -property ($caseprops | convertfrom-stringdata)

 $case | add-member aliasproperty "RT" "Remaining Time - Hours"

 $case | fl

 Remaining Time - Hours : 22.5
 Starred                : No
 Category               : Inquiry
 RT                     : 22.5
```

Comment: I love the way you created your object.  Haven't seen convertfrom-stringdata before...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is old, but you can also do this if you need to access properties with spaces in them:

```
$case | Select-Object ("Remaining Time - Hours"), ("Another Property")
```