# Access powershell property with space in name

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I have the following:

```
$test = Test-CsWebScheduler -TargetFqdn "pool.int.contoso.com"
Write-Output $test

Target Fqdn   : pool.int.contoso.com
Target Uri    : https://pool.int.contoso.com/Scheduler/
Result        : Failure
Latency       : 00:00:00
Error Message : Scheduling conference at
                https://pool.int.contoso.com/Scheduler/Handler/WebSchedulerHandler.ashx failed
                with status Failure.

Diagnosis     :
```

The question is now:

How can I access the "Error Message", "Target Uri" or the "Target Fqdn"? I can access the result via:

```
Write-Output $test.result
Failure
```

without problems, but as the others have a space inside it, I haven´t found a way to access them. I tried the following (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857792/powershell-reference-a-property-that-contains-a-space)):

```
Write-Output $test."Target Uri"
```

or

```
Write-Output $test.{Target Uri}
```

I also tried the following:

```
$test | Select-Object -Property "Target Uri"
```

or

```
Write-Output ($test."Target Uri")
```

or the very simple:

```
$test."Target Uri"
```

but that's not working and I do not get a value back (also no error). The only error message I get is when I use:

```
$test | select -ExpandProperty "Target Uri"

select : Property "Target Uri" cannot be found.
At line:1 char:9
+ $test | select -ExpandProperty "Target Uri"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Rtc.S...s.WebTaskOutput:PSObject) [Selec
   t-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCom
   mand
```

Did anybody have an idea how i can access that (without dumping that to a temp file and parse it)?

**Update 01:**

as requested here is the output from $test | gm

```
$test | gm

   TypeName: Microsoft.Rtc.SyntheticTransactions.WebTaskOutput

Name           MemberType Definition
----           ---------- ----------
Equals         Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode    Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType        Method     type GetType()
ToString       Method     string ToString()
Diagnosis      Property   string Diagnosis {get;}
Error          Property   string Error {get;}
Latency        Property   timespan Latency {get;}
Result         Property   Microsoft.Rtc.SyntheticTransactions.ResultStatus Result {get;}
TargetFqdn     Property   string TargetFqdn {get;}
TargetUri      Property   string TargetUri {get;}
WorkflowLogger Property   Microsoft.Rtc.SyntheticTransactions.Logging.SyntheticTransactionsWorkf...
```

Comment: `$test."Target Uri"` - should work fine; can you paste (update the question) output from `$test | gm`?

Comment: yes i would expect that too, but as written above, that isn´t the case.

Comment: There is no difference when i use `Write-Output ($test."Target Uri")` or `$test."Target Uri"`... the output from `$test | gm` was added now to my original posting.

Comment: @PetSerAl I do not see a difference in using `,$test | gm` or `$test | gm` as already asked above. It looks like the same to me.
@Ansgar Didn´t got your point. The whole code is mentioned above. There is nothing special or transformation done. Simply open a powershell and run the command.

Comment: You requested to show the output from `,$test | gm` but i already updated my question here with `$test | gm` and there is no difference between your command and the one from @4c74356b41. And yes `$test.result` is working and shows a result as written in my question, so `$test` couldn´t be empty.

Comment: @PetSerAl sure i did run it but there is no difference in running `$test | gm` and your one `,$test | gm` or I didn´t saw it. The output from `$test | gm` is pasted into the original question.

Comment: @BastianW As now you edited your questing and provide very different output for `$test | gm`. You should clearly see that property names do not actually have space it them. It should be `$test.TargetUri` not `$test.'Target Uri'`.

Comment: @PetSerAl yes it looks like that sometimes the test command produce a kind of timeout, then the result is different and shows therefore different property names. I can reproduce that. Every 2-3 attempt showed a different output for `$test | gm` ... quite strange... @ 4c74356b41 as you where the first one who tried to point to the `$test | gm` which lead to the solution can you please build an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: Using the "names" seen in the output didn´t mean they are identically with the real property names. However with using [Get-Member (or the short abbreviation GM)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176854.aspx) the real property names stored inside the variable can be checked.

So using

```
$test | gm
```

or

```
$test | Get-Member
```

Showed that the "Target Uri" is "TargetUri":

```
[...]
TargetUri      Property   string TargetUri {get;}
[...]
```

So using:

```
$test.TargetUri
```

solved that question here.

Answer (score 0):

As seen when piping the $test variable to get-member

```
$test | gm
```

The output provided has shown that the Target URI property is actually one word, so simply using the following will work for you in your script.

```
$test.TargetUri
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to access to the value like this:

```
$test.PSObject.Properties["Target Uri"].Value
```