# How do I deal with dashes in a property name in powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax, properties

I am trying to write the Active Directory parameter msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress to a variable in powershell.  For some reason, it seems to be choking on the dash in the property name.  Does anyone know a way around it?  I was able put other property in the variable that do not have a dash.

```
$sip = $sipaccount.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress
```

Anyone ever run into this?  Know of a way around it?

Comment: You can use quotes around a property name to make sure it is parsed as a string: `$sipaccount.'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: Reference a property that contains a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857792/powershell-reference-a-property-that-contains-a-space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put it in quotes like so:

```
$sip = $sipaccount.'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel ridiculous that I didn't try that.

Comment: Haha, it's okay, that's what we're here for :)