# POWERSHELL : Get-IssuedRequest can't display property request.requestername

Tags: powershell, properties

I have an issue to display a property from cmdlet.

```
$IssuedCERTS = Get-IssuedRequest -CertificationAuthority server.xx.xom | where { $_.CertificateTemplate -match "xx" -or $_.CertificateTemplate -match "xx" }
```

That property is working :

```
PS C:\Users\xx>$IssuedCERTS.requestid 
1212
1214
```

But that property don't  :

```
PS C:\Users\xx>$IssuedCERTS.Request.RequesterName
```

No output.

All others properties are working.

```
PS C:\Users\xx> $IssuedCERTS | get-member
   TypeName : SysadminsLV.PKI.Management.CertificateServices.Database.AdcsDbRow
Name                   MemberType   Definition
----                   ----------   ----------
Equals                 Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode            Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType                Method       type GetType()
ToString               Method       string ToString()
CertificateTemplate    NoteProperty string CertificateTemplate=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.11025665.8001721.14437036.989286.13682...
CertificateTemplateOid NoteProperty Oid CertificateTemplateOid=System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
CommonName             NoteProperty string xxxxx
NotAfter               NoteProperty datetime NotAfter=29/02/2024 13:43:32
NotBefore              NoteProperty datetime NotBefore=01/03/2023 13:43:32
Request.RequesterName  NoteProperty string Request.RequesterName=xxxxx
RequestID              NoteProperty int RequestID=1212
SerialNumber           NoteProperty string SerialNumber=1a000004bc2601c2d88674658a0000000004bc
ConfigString           Property     string ConfigString {get;set;}
Properties             Property     SysadminsLV.PKI.Management.CertificateServices.Database.AdcsDbPropertyCollection Prope...
RowId                  Property     int RowId {get;set;}
Table                  Property     SysadminsLV.PKI.Management.CertificateServices.Database.AdcsDbTableName Table {get;set;}
```

I suppose this is because there is a dot in property?
How can i show porperty?
Select-object works but that displays request.requestername like a tab and i juste want DOMAIN\user

```
PS C:\Users\xx> $IssuedCERTS | select request.requestername

Request.RequesterName
---------------------
DOMAIN\user
DOMAIN\user
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$IssuedCERTS."Request.RequesterName"`?

Comment: YES! You can post it as answer.Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you!. But I would mark [this as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857792/powershell-reference-a-property-that-contains-a-space) instead.

Comment: yes it answers the question